# Avoid dx/dy attributes in d3 axis labels

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I experienced problems with the position of text elements when exporting SVG files and opening it in Corel Draw (some older version). I fixed it by setting every dx/dy attribute to zero and added its value to the corresponding x/y attribute.

I wrote a helper function which is called with .each on every text element I use.

```
transformDXYtoXY: function(d, i) {
    var that = d3.select(this);

    var y = that.attr("y") == null ? 0 : parseFloat(that.attr("y"));
    var dy = that.attr("dy") == null ? 0 : parseFloat(that.attr("dy"));
    that.attr("y", y + dy);
    that.attr("dy", 0);

    // doing the same with dx/x
    ...
},
```

This was working great until I decided to transition axis on input change instead of redraw them:

```
axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(someScale);
d3.select('.axis')
    .transition()
    .call(axis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .each(transformDXYtoXY);
```

Without the call to `transformDXYtoXY()` the tick label position is off
The `y/dy` attributes are not being set, even though when I check for it inside `transformDXYtoXY()` it seems allright.

Is there a way to tell d3 to avoid using `dx/dy`? It looks like the problem occurs during `transition()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the `dx` and `dy` attributes is hardcoded in the source of D3 -- changing it would be a significant effort. However, there's an easy workaround. D3 transitions allow you to set up a [listener for the end of the transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each). You can leverage this to run your code to fix the attribute values (with minimal changes to your existing code):

```
d3.select('.axis')
  .transition()
  .call(axis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .each("end", transformDXYtoXY);
```

To clarify, the code that you have at the moment runs the function to fix the attributes immediately after setting up the transition which then runs and overwrites the attribute values. The code above runs the function after the transition is complete, i.e. no further attribute changes will occur.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not helping either. I put together this plunk to demonstrate my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/rLZECVQin2ArVUoAxVYV?p=preview

Comment: You can't call several functions on it this way -- the order of execution (which you rely on) isn't guaranteed. Wrap them in a single function and call that: http://plnkr.co/edit/u0VfezBJmfcHYawSnVzz?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. This way it works even without the "end" event listener